# How to properly convert my syntax from string to array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am creating a project in android studio. My goal is: when i click the "load" button i would like the data in `edittextName` + `edittextPhone` strings recall the data previously saved and to dispay it back after the app has closed and been reopened

When i try to run my project, i get the error message "**array found, string required**"

i believe all i need to do is to change the `[]` into a `get()` command but don't know the correct syntax to use.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourite);


    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneText);

    file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);

}

public void save(View v) {
    String data = editTextName.getText().toString() + "|" + editTextPhone.getText().toString();
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Barcrawl has been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}

public void load(View v) {
    int length = (int) file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream.read(bytes);
        inputStream.close();
        String data = new String(bytes);
        editTextName.setText(data.split("\\|"[0])); // << problem
        editTextPhone.setText(data.split("\\|"[1])); // << problem
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "data loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am new the android studio and have been stuck on this for awhile, please help.

Comment: Did you intend to do this: `editTextName.setText(data.split("\\|")[0])` ?  `String#split` returns an array of strings.  You may then access an element in that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.split("\\|")` returns `String[]`,  you can change it to this:

```
editTextName.setText(data.split("\\|")[0]);  
editTextPhone.setText(data.split("\\|")[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it, legend!